# ¿Se puede simular un input en un div?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<span>//texto obtenido mediante javascript</span>
```

//mi intencion es obtener el texto mediante jquery para introducirlo en un span, mi intencion no es utilizar un 'input' o un 'textarea' por que lo que quiero es que el span sea de heigth: auto. Pero lo que quiero simular es la barra que titila en un input al estar en focus, si no me entienden dare mas explicaciones

Comment: Creo que lo buscas es esto [typed.js](https://mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/)

Comment: También podrías estar buscando esto otro [quill.js](https://quilljs.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claro que se puede simular un `input` en un elemento `div` o `span`. Existe en HTML un atributo global llamado `contenteditable` que indica si el elemento debe de ser editable por el usuario. Puedes leer más sobre esto [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/contenteditable).

Por otro lado, simulándolo, quedaría así:

```html
<div style="padding:5px;font-size:20px;background-color:#000;color:#fff;min-height:30px;" contenteditable="true">
HOLA SOY UN CONTENIDO EDITABLE
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva para lo que necesites. Saludos.

Comment: muchisimas gracias, me siervio de mucho, la verdad que no conocia el atributo *contenteditable*, hay alguna posibilidad de poder agregarle un *placeholder* ?

Comment: Hola, no hay forma de ponerle un placeholder.